# Getting an exchange by name without knowing its type

Tags: java, spring-amqp

As a message consumer, I'm trying to create a queue and a binding. Creating a binding requires a reference to an exchange, for example:

```
Binding b = BindingBuilder.bind(new Queue("queue")).to(new DirectExchange("directex")).with("routingkey");
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a reference to an exchange only by name and without necessarily knowing its type or other properties (such as its durability and whether it will auto delete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `new Binding(...)` instead of using the builder.